# If I followed vs if I follow

Tags: word-choice

1. Would you mind if I followed you?
2. Would you mind if I follow you?

Is there any difference in meaning? Would both be said by a native speaker?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, there is no difference in meaning.

Native speakers would use either the *present tense* or *past tense* depending on the circumstance.  Your example is ambiguous, so either tense may work.